# Relation of roots of a polynomial to amplitude distribution of its coefficients

Tags: discrete-signals, filter-design, poles-zeros

Consider $g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{p}a_kx^{k}$, and let $\{\tau_1,\tau_2,\cdots,\tau_p\}\in\mathbb{C}$ be the roots of $g(x)$. What is the relation between how $\{a_0,a_1,\cdots,a_p\}$ are distributed (in amplitude values) and the magnitude of roots of $g(x)$?
Is there a condition on amplitude distribution of $a_k$s and degree $p$ which can aid in making all the roots to lie inside the unit circle.

An example: Below plot shows roots of 1000 polynomials each for degree $p = 5,10,20,50,100$ in $g(x)$ above {depicted in 'r.','g.','b.','k.' colours, respectively}. In each trial p+1 random numbers are drawn from Normal distribution $\mathcal{N}(0,1)$. [Right sub-plot]: The random numbers are assigned as $a_k$s. [Left sub-plot]: The random numbers are sorted in descending order and assigned as $a_k$s such that $a_{k-1}<a_k$. In the Left sub-plot, roots tend to move towards unit circle specifically for higher degrees.

[image: Plot showing the roots of the 1000 polynomials. In each trial the d+1 random numbers are drawn from Normal distribution N(0,1). [Right]: The random numbers are assigned as $a_k$s. [Left]: The random numbers are sorted in descending order and assigned as $a_k$s such that $a_{k-1}<a_k$]

Comment: Hints: $a_0 = \frac{1}{a_p}\prod_{i=1}^p (-\tau_i), a_i, a_{p-1} = -\frac{1}{a_p}\sum_{i=1}^p \tau_i$, and a -1 for the lousy choice of notation where $p$ is the name of the polynomial and its degree as well.

Comment: I not able to proceed to bound $\max_i|\tau_i|$ with these conditions.

Comment: There are several bounds on the roots presented here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Properties_of_polynomial_roots.

Comment: What is it that you want to achieve? I'm pretty convinced that there is no simple way to constrain the coefficients $a_k$ (for higher polynomial degrees) such that the roots are inside the unit circle. There is also no useful recursive filter (that can be implemented) with a denominator of degree 50 or 100. Moreover, it could very well be that what you're observing are numerical artifacts, because computing the zeros of a polynomial of degree 100 is very error prone.

Comment: Inside the unit disk could be a more correct formulation, or do you mean 'lie on the unit disk'? In the first case, you may look at Rouché's theorem, see [All the zeroes of $p(z)$ lie inside the unit disk](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/328850/all-the-zeroes-of-pz-lie-inside-the-unit-disk).

Comment: @Matt L. Interestingly you can factorize high degree polynomials (>5000 order) using library codes, such as roots() function in MATLAB. It converts a polynomial into a companion matrix and then finds the eigenvalues of that matrix. Alternate approaches also exists (just search on Factoring very high degree polynomials). The observations in the figure are not numerical artifacts as the polynomial can be constructed back from the obtained roots.

Comment: @LaurentDuval Thank you for the reference. I see the problem given there is similar and gives the insight I needed. However, I discovered that it needs a condition of $|a_{k-1}|\leq|a_k|$ and not just $a_{k-1}\leq a_k$ (which is the case in my simulation plots above and hence some roots go outside unit circle).

Comment: Indeed. I also suggest the SE.math post in [roots of polynomials outside the unit disc](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/67049/roots-of-polynomials-outside-the-unit-disc) and the name of the [Lehmer-Schur method](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lehmer-Schur_Method)

Comment: If you checked all randomly chosen polynomials and there were no numerical issues then I guess you're quite lucky. I know from experience that finding the roots of polynomials of much lower degree than 100 can be a very ill-conditioned problem.